# 'classnames' should be listed in the project's dependencies (import/no-extraneous-dependencies) *YARN

Tags: git, eslint

I got this error after installing "classnames" through yarn 1.22.19.
What is the deal?

There is "classnames" in my package.json

I tried run yarn, yarn install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot system is a resolving way.

Another option to solve this problem may be removing node_modules `rm -rf /node_modules` and install dependenices again. In my opinion, the issue could be connected with file linking